How to insert a widget inline with text in Flutter without forcing a new line?
In Flutter, I want to insert a widget (an icon) at the end of a text block, but I want to ensure that the widget stays inline with the last word of the text and doesn't wrap to a new line by itself. If the text is super long, the text should be cut off. Otherwise words can be split.
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: title,
        style: textStyle,
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
          child: icon,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)

I've tried putting the icon in a row with the last character but then it doesn't move the last word itself onto the next line in some cases.
The first two images are as expected.
The last image here shows what I'm trying to avoid:




Provide image on the result that you except to see can let others to help you better in achieving that. Thanks.

Just added the images

did you checked the list tile widget?

you can share the widget you want to get, maybe there is a way to make it in another way..

I looked over list tile widgets. It seems it only works for one line of text. I don't want the icon to span over multiple lines.

Well, I believe it’s not possible to directly achieve this without manipulating the "String" that you want to place next to the icon. This is because spaces between words break once there's no more space in the line.
However, I came up with a sort of "workaround" that might help. I created two functions to manipulate the provided text: _onlyLastWords and _withoutLastWords. I made it so that if you want to increase or decrease the number of words, you only need to change the value of words.
String _onlyLastWords(String text, {int words = 2}) {
  List<String> wordsOfText = text.split(" ");

  return " ${wordsOfText.sublist(wordsOfText.length - words).join(" ")}";
}

String _withoutLastWords(String text, {int words = 2}) {
  List<String> wordsOfText = text.split(" ");
  return wordsOfText.sublist(0, wordsOfText.length - words).join(" ");
}

With this, I structured it like this:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  String _onlyLastWords(String text, {int words = 2}) {
    List<String> wordsOfText = text.split(" ");

    return " ${wordsOfText.sublist(wordsOfText.length - words).join(" ")}";
  }

  String _withoutLastWords(String text, {int words = 2}) {
    List<String> wordsOfText = text.split(" ");
    return wordsOfText.sublist(0, wordsOfText.length - words).join(" ");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 900,
          child: Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: _withoutLastWords(text),
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(_onlyLastWords(text)),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.import_contacts),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The idea is to create an element with the last two words plus the icon, so that when there’s no space, there are always at least two words before the icon.



Thank you, but what if the last word takes up the entire line? In this case, I would want the word to get cut off onto the next line

So, if I understood correctly, you don't want the new line to have only the icon if the text is long enough to break onto a new line, right?

Correct. I want at least one character on the left of the icon. Sorry if that wasn't clear

In this case, we can adjust by even removing the functions, removing the last one and taking the last character, but I believe it will look a bit strange as it will "break" the word.
It will look like (wor
d icon).
Is that what you want?

A simpler way would be to use Unicode like this --new Text('2018 \u00a9 Author's Name'),

Thanks for the suggestion, this may be the best solution I can find.

You can extract the last word and place it in the Row with the icon inside the WidgetSpan. In the code below, I have place the word hello with the icon ABC inside the Row and placed the Row inside the WidgetSpan.
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'My icon is always connectedd with hello.',
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text('hello'),
                        Icon(Icons.abc),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Thank you. I've tried doing something similar. The problem is if the word is very long, it's gonna overflow. I want at least one character on the left of the icon.

 Flexible(                           child: Text(                             'hellohellohellohellohello',                             maxLines: 1,                             overflow: TextOverflow.clip,                           ),                         ),                         SizedBox(                           width: 10,                           child: Icon(Icons.abc),                         ),                         SizedBox(                           width: 10,                         ),
Then use it like this inside the Row
